# What does "GC--" in gc.log mean?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What does “GC--” mean in a java garbage collection log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174976/what-does-gc-mean-in-a-java-garbage-collection-log)

Consider this snippet of a gc.log

> 22760.000: [GC [PSYoungGen: 3900952K->68748K(4035904K)] 12250344K->8418140K(12424512K), 0.0200860 secs] [Times: user=0.21 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
>
> 22774.793: [GC-- [PSYoungGen: 3937932K->3937932K(4035904K)] 12287324K->12326532K(12424512K), 0.9267780 secs] [Times: user=2.41 sys=1.35, real=0.93 secs]
>
> 22775.721: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 3937932K->0K(4035904K)] [PSOldGen: 8388600K->7444523K(8388608K)] 12326532K->7444523K(12424512K) [PSPermGen: 70788K->70788K(86016K)], 5.7656510 secs] [Times: user=5.66 sys=0.04, real=5.77 secs]

Everything is understandable, but the second entry beginning with `GC--`.

What does it mean? It seems that this "collection" increased the memory usage to the max capacity. Right after this entry is a full gc.